# Remove CRLF at the end of every string in Text Files Python

Tags: python-3.x, newline

I am converting pdf files into images and then into Text Files (using Python). I need to read all the text files I converted from PDF to Text and remove the CRLF from the end of each string.

My text file looks something like this:

**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla**CRLF**
**CRLF**

I want to remove the CRFL at the end of every string, but leave those that are on their own on an empty line (i.e there is no string before it)

This is my first time posting on Stackoverflow, so bear with me.

Edit: I want to fix the files I have and not create new ones. The aim is to have the paragraphs kept as intended, because otherwise when I read the file, it reads it line by line and does not return a paragraph but a line because of the CRFL at the end of each string.

I have this code but it's not doing anything:

```
txt_filepaths = glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive=True)
start = time.time()

def paragraph():
    #clean text file
    TextFile = os.listdir(save_text_path)
    TextFile.sort()
    this_text = open(save_text_path + name, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
    
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        lines = list(fp) #text as a list
        Text1 = []
        row = []
        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line:
                        #if not row:
                        #    results.append('\n')
                row.append(line)
            else:
                if row:
                    Text1.append(' '.join(row))
                    row = []

                # for last element this code has to be after loop
        if row:
            Text1.append(' '.join(row))
            row = []
        
        this_text.write(Text1)
        print('Processing next page')
    this_text.close()
    
print(f"Program took {time.time() - start} seconds")
```

Comment: the issue is that when it does work it removes all of them or none. I can't get it to just remove the ones that are at the end of a string.

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to get it working during the convert2text function with the following:**for i in range(len(jpgFiles)):
        Text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(destination_jpg + jpgFiles[i]),
                                            config="tessdata_dir_config --psm 6 --oem 1")\
        .replace('\n\n', " new_paragraph ")\
        .replace('\n', " ")\
        .replace("new_paragraph", '\n')\** and ended up not using the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much KJ, I managed to get it working during the convert2text function with the following:

```
for i in range(len(jpgFiles)): 
Text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(destination_jpg + jpgFiles[i]), config="tessdata_dir_config --psm 6 --oem 1")\
.replace('\n\n', " new_paragraph ")\ 
.replace('\n', " ")\ 
.replace("new_paragraph", '\n')
<br>
```

and ended up not the initial code I posted within the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go over the file using a `for` loop with `fp.readlines()` and just check if the line starts with `\n`
For example:

```
with open(save_text_path + name, "a", encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as in_file:
        for line in in_file.readlines():
            if line.startswith('\n'):
                out_file.write('\n')
            else:
                out_file.write(line.strip('\n'))
```

Also check out this way of reading a file and writing to another one on the same time, making the code much cleaner and pythonic

Comment: This isn't doing anything either. Your answer is actually answering something else I'm looking to do which is to remove the \n from strings that start with a certain word. However, it's not working for me. I just replace the '\n' on line 4 and 5 with the specific word. I'm not the best at this, so apologies if these questions may seem stupid....

Comment: ~~~
`save_text_path = "....OCR_TextFiles/"`

`def bullet_point(name):`
    `with open(save_text_path + name, "a", encoding="utf-8") as out_file:`
        `with open(save_text_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as in_file:`
            `for line in in_file.readlines():`
                `if line.startswith('Bullet_Point'):`
                    `out_file.write('Bullet_Point')`
               `else:`
                    `out_file.write(line.strip('\n'))`
~~~